# receive UDP packages on localhost (java.net.BindException: Address already in use)

Tags: java, server, udp, client, port

I have an application that runs an udp server on a certain port to communicate with the app.

When I try to write another java application that receives what the server is sending, I get the error "java.net.BindException: Address already in use". What am I doing wrong? Why can't my application bind to that port?

my code:

```
package osc.bridge;
//import com.illposed.osc.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class OSCbridge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        
        try{
            int port = 17002;
            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
            byte[] receiveBuf = new byte[65535];
            DatagramPacket dpReceive = null;
            
            while(true) {
                dpReceive = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuf, receiveBuf.length);
                ds.receive(dpReceive);
                
                System.out.println(receiveBuf[0]);

                
                receiveBuf = new byte[65535];
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        

    }

}
```

I already tried to run my application without the server is running, but then my server-application throws an error because it can't start the server...